# How to get some part of audio file in Objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio, core-audio, avaudioplayer

I would like to get some part of audio file in Objective-C. 
For example from 20 minutes length of audio, I want only 5 minute length.
and also save it to a new audio file (that can be opened and played).
The reason is that I want to reduce the size of it.

Another question is that is there the way to convert the audio format to another 
that is smaller size

Comment: It's not that hard to read in the file and access the individual bytes.  Unfortunately, I'm not on the box where I've done some of that or I'd give you more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to use AVFoundation. You can load the audio file into an [AVAsset](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAsset_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and then use [AVExportSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetExportSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVAssetExportSession) to save the part of the audio file you want to another file.

See the [AVMovieExporter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVMovieExporter) sample on the Apple developer site.